# Should i be using forceUpdate() or finding another way to rerender React component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, axios

I have this component and I would like to rerender after my api call. I cant figure out why after api call of getWinks, winks-count does update but not on the view unless I refresh. Should I not be using this.forceUpdate(). Please advise and any criticism is welcome.

```
export default class Winks extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.insertDecimal = this.insertDecimal.bind(this)
    this.state = ({
      user:cookie.load('user',
    )})
    console.log(this.state)
    this.httpHandler = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'localhost:3000',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': this.state.user.token
      }
    })
  }

  insertDecimal(num) {
     var num = (num / 100).toFixed(2);
     return '$' + num
  }
 getWinks (itemId) {
   this.httpHandler.post("/users/" + this.state.user.id + "/winks", {
      user_id:this.state.user.id,
      wink: {
        product_id:itemId
      }
   }).then(function (response){
     this.forceUpdate()
   }.bind(this))
 }

  render () {
    var listItems = this.props.products.map(function(item, index,) {
      var wink = item.attributes
      if (index % 5 ===0) {
        return (
          <Col lg={2} md={4} sm={4} xs={6}>
            <div className="item">
              <img className='img-responsive' src={wink["image-url"]}></img>
              <div className="item-meta">
                <span className="name">{wink.name}</span>
                <span className="site"> Bloomingdales.com</span>
                <div className="rate">
                  <span className="old">{this.insertDecimal(wink.price)}</span>
                  <span className="new">{this.insertDecimal(wink["sale-price"])}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="like">
                  <i onClick={()=>this.getWinks(item.id)} className="fa fa-heart"></i>
                  <span>{wink["winks-count"]}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Col>
        )
      }
      else {
        return (
          <Col lg={2} md={4} sm={4} xs={6}>
            <div className="item">
              <img className='img-responsive' src={wink["image-url"]}></img>
              <div className="item-meta">
                <span className="name">{wink.name}</span>
                <span className="site"> Bloomingdales.com</span>
                <div className="rate">
                  <span className="old">{this.insertDecimal(wink.price)}</span>
                  <span className="new">{this.insertDecimal(wink["sale-price"])}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="like">
                  <i onClick={()=>this.getWinks(item.id)} className="fa fa-heart"></i>
                  <span>{wink["winks-count"]}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Col>
        )
      }
    }.bind(this));
    return (
        <Row className="item-row">
          {listItems}
        </Row>
    )
  }
}
```

Parent component:

```
export default class AllItems extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state=({ user: cookie.load('user')})
    this.httpHandler = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'localhost:3000',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': this.state.user.token
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.httpHandler('/products/')
    .then(function (response) {
      this.setState({ winks: response.data.data})
    }.bind(this))
  }
  render() {

      return (
        <Grid>
          <div className="item-wrapper">
            <Row>
              <h1 className="text-center">All Items</h1>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={2}>
                <div className="item-sidebar-wrapper">
                  <div className="sort">
                    <Sort />
                  </div>
                  <div className="category">
                    <Category />
                  </div>
                  <div className="price">
                    <Price />
                  </div>
                  <div className="size">
                    <Size />
                  </div>
                  <div className="color">
                    <Color />
                  </div>
                  <div className="brand">
                    <Brand />
                  </div>
                  <div className="stores">
                    <Stores />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={10}>
                <Winks products={this.state.winks} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should never have to use `forceUpdate()`. Instead, you should be using `this.setState()` to update the data, as it will make your component re-render automatically using the new data.

It's not clear from your example, but assuming that the `response` parameter in the `getWinks()` method contains the updated products, it should be used to update the state.

But since you get the initial products from the parent, using props, you need to pass the updated products back to the parent and let it run `this.setState({ products })` (which will trigger a re-render, and in turn cause the component you show to re-render with the new data).

Comment: So in this situation its actually this.props.winks that I would want to pass back from Winks to AllItems? or should i make another api call to get updated this.state.winks. Currently I have an api call to get all products in the parent componenet, then I passed it down to Winks where I use a post route to update each product

Comment: What does `response` contain in the `getWinks()` method?

Comment: {
            "id": "9",
            "type": "winks",
            "attributes": {
                "created-at": "2016-09-21T20:57:19.640Z",
                "updated-at": "2016-09-21T20:57:19.640Z"
            },

Comment: it doesnt give me a winks_count which the original api call in parent component does, do you think i should just make an api call again to get products

Comment: In that case, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `state`. Say, use a state `loader`, it should set to `true` when you call the `httpHandler` and to `false` when the async action is completed. This way, changing the state will re-render the component without any `forceupdate()`

Something like this.

```
getWinks (itemId) {
   this.setState({loading: true})
   this.httpHandler.post("/users/" + this.state.user.id + "/winks", {
      user_id:this.state.user.id,
      wink: {
        product_id:itemId
      }
   }).then(function (response){
     this.setState({loading: false})
   }.bind(this)) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component doesn't rerender because you aren't changing its state nor props so it doesn't have anything to update, that's just simply how react works.

In your code you're sending POST request but you don't do anything with response. Can you explain what does this request do?

Answer (score 0):

Your component is a function of `props` and `state`. So anytime they change, your component renders again.

If the `state` or the `props` passed to your component change from a call to `setState(...)` on the component or any parent component, then your component will render again. Therefore, the only time your would use `forceupdate()` is when you need the component to render as a function of something else.

For instance, suppose you have a `Timer` component that is being passed the properties `elapsed` and `runningSince`. The `Timer` component would compute the time displayed to the user based on `elapsed`, `runningSince`, and `Date.now()`. However, `elapsed` and `runningSince` won't change unless the user clicks the start or stop button. But then the `Timer` component won't show a live timer because nothing is going to trigger it's `render` function. To solve this problem, you would add an update interval that would call `forceupdate()` every `50 ms`, for example.